# AWS SAM local start-api does not print any errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I use the AWS SAM application and SAM template to mimic the API service (API Gateway and Lambda). Lambda is running on Python 3.8.

Recently, I have upgraded to the latest version of the SAM cli. I use the command 'sam local start-api' and debug the code by calling the rest api service with Postman.

When there are some bugs in the code, it used to print the Python errors in the command prompt but the recent upgrade of the cli does not print out the errors anymore. It just print the line where it stopped but it does not give any errors or exceptions.

I tried to run it with debug mode on 'sam local start-api --debug' but this did not help.

Is there any change and any workaround to print Python errors when running SAM cli?

I tried to run it with debug mode on 'sam local start-api --debug' but this did not help.

Is there any change and any workaround to print Python errors when running SAM cli?